# Can't re-deploy app previously deployed to another account

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that I previously deployed to my now-defunct account on `shinyapps.io`. When I try to re-deploy using:

```
deployApp(appName="my_app")
```

I get the error message:

```
Error: Please specify the account you want to deploy
'my_app' to (you have previously deployed this application
to more than one account).
```

So I specify:

```
deployApp(account="new_account",appName="my_app")
```

But now I get the error:

```
Error in serverInfo(server) : 
  name must be a single element character vector
```

Based on this [bug report](https://github.com/rstudio/rsconnect/issues/202), it sounds like I need to specify a server, but I am not sure where to find this information. For example, `serverInfo()` returns an error as well.

**How can I get the relevant server info, or better yet, how can I deploy the app without all these workarounds?**

Comment: Have you tried the point and click interface in RStudio?

Comment: @jsb Solved! Thank you.